# How to speed up scraping large amounts of data with Python

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, memory-optimization

I have the following code:

```
items = set()  # use a set to not have duplicate items
a = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}?{BASE_QUERIES}&cursor=*")

amount = a.json()["totalResults"]  # in the range of 30 million

items.update(item["guid"].split("?")[0] for item in a.json()["items"])  # we only want the url before the query strings

cursor = a.json()["nextCursor"]  # we have a cursor as each request only returns 100 items, the cursor shows use where to start

while len(items) < amount:  # ensure we get all the items
    try:
        a = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}?{BASE_QUERIES}&cursor={cursor}")
        items.update(item["guid"].split("?")[0] for item in a.json()["items"])
    except:
        continue
    try:
        cursor = urllib.parse.quote(a.json()["nextCursor"])
    except KeyError:
        if len(items) == amount:  # when we reach the final iteration the cursor will not be there
            break

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
}

for link in items:  # iterate over each item
    for _ in range(3):
        response = requests.get(link, headers=headers, stream=True)
        response.raw.decode_content = True
        parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(response.raw, parser)

        setting = tree.xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a/span[1]/text()"
        )[0].strip()
        try:
            image = tree.xpath(
                "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/a/@href"
            )[0]  # most of the time this works
        except:
            try:
                image = tree.xpath(
                    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href"
                )[0]  # about 1 in 10 times the above fails and this works
            except:
                print(f"Image not found for link: {link}")
                break

        title = tree.findtext(".//title")
        title_for_file = (
            fr"{os.getcwd()}\IMAGES\IMAGE - " + "".join(c for c in title if c in valid_chars) + ".jpeg"
        )  # sometimes the file contains characters which aren't allowed in file names

        description = "".join(
            tree.xpath(
                "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/p/text()"
            )
        )

        if setting not in [x, y]:  # we only want items which have a specific setting
            break

        try:
            image_req = requests.get(image)
            with open(title_for_file, "wb") as f:
                f.write(image_req.content)  # write the image to the directory

            img = pyexiv2.Image(title_for_file)
            metadata = {"Xmp.xmp.Title": title, "Xmp.xmp.Description": description}  # edit the metadata
            img.modify_xmp(metadata)
            img.close()
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(
                f"ERROR parsing image: {title_for_file}, it is most likely corrupt, "
                f"retrying ({link}), "
                f"error: {e}"
            )
            os.remove(title_for_file)
    else:
        print("ERROR more than 3 times moving to next")
```

The code has some fairly detailed comments to explain what it does, my issue is that it takes about 7 hours to do all the requests to get the links in `items`, then another (I'm not 100% sure but, I think about 1500 hours) to check each image and add the metadata. Is there *anything* in this code that can be sped up/refined to speed up this process?

Similarly, is there anywhere I could reduce memory usage as I *suspect* this will use **alot** of memory with the amount of data it is parsing.

**EDIT**

A possible consideration would be to use `Threading` to download multiple images at once, how would one find the optimal number of threads to run at once? Or perhaps I would start each `Thread` with a small delay, perhaps 0.5 seconds?

Comment: How large are these images? If they were 3MB each, it would take [more than 80 days just to download them (sequentially, assuming 100 Mbit/s speed)(https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30E6+*+3MB+%2F+100Mbit%2Fs).

Comment: Approximately 500kB-1MB, so yes still a lot! Hence, why I need to reduce as much as possible, obviously the bulk of the time is the requests. But, I am not necessarily downloading all of these images, I expect to download about 1/2 as about 1/2 will not be in `x` or `y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can start thinking about doing fancy things like parallelizing this code, you should start by putting your code into functions that do one thing each.

```
def get_items(response):
    # we only want the url before the query strings
    # use a set to not have duplicate items
    return {item["guid"].split("?")[0] for item in response["items"]}

def get_all_items():
    url = f"{BASE_URL}?{BASE_QUERIES}"
    response = requests.get(url, params={"cursor": "*"}).json()
    amount = response["totalResults"]  # in the range of 30 million
    items = get_items(response)        
    while cursor := response.get("nextCursor"):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, params={"cursor": cursor}).json()
            items.update(get_items(response))
        except Exception:
            continue
    if len(items) != amount:
        raise ValueError("Did not get all items")
    return items
```

Note that I changed your bare `except` to an `except Exception`, otherwise the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would also be ignored.

I also used the new walrus operator to continue iterating as long as a `nextCursor` is given in the response.

```
HEADERS = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
}

ALLOWED_SETTINGS = {x, y}

def handle_link(link, retries=3):
    for _ in range(retries):
        if parse(link, ALLOWED_SETTINGS):
            break

def parse(link, allowed_settings):
    response = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS, stream=True)
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(response.raw, parser)
    setting = get_setting(tree)
    if setting not in allowed_settings:  # we only want items which have a specific setting
        return False
    image = get_image(tree)
    if image is None:
        return False
    title = get_title(tree)
    file_name = get_file_name(title)
    description = get_description(tree)
    return save_image(image, file_name,
                      {"Xmp.xmp.Title": title, "Xmp.xmp.Description": description})
```

Note that I aborted as soon as possible, no need to continue parsing if the `setting` already tells you that you will throw the result away.

```
def get_setting(tree):
    return tree.xpath(
        "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a/span[1]/text()"
    )[0].strip()

def get_image(tree):
    xpaths = ["/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/a/@href",
              "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href"]
    for xpath in xpaths:
        try:
            return tree.xpath(xpath)[0]
        except Exception:                
            continue
    print(f"Image not found for link: {link}")

def get_title(tree):
    return tree.findtext(".//title")

def get_file_name(title):
    return (
        fr"{os.getcwd()}\IMAGES\IMAGE - " + "".join(c for c in title if c in valid_chars) + ".jpeg"
    )  # sometimes the file contains characters which aren't allowed in file names

def get_description(tree):
    return "".join(
        tree.xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/p/text()"
        )
    )

def save_image(url, file_name, metadata):
    try:
        image_req = requests.get(url)
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(image_req.content)  # write the image to the directory
        img = pyexiv2.Image(file_name)
        img.modify_xmp(metadata)
        img.close()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(
            f"ERROR parsing image: {file_name}, it is most likely corrupt, "
            f"error: {e}"
        )
        os.remove(file_name)
        return False
```

With this you could now start thinking about parallelization, since you actually have an encapsulated target function to execute.

Since there are now also separate functions for getting some information, you can consider changing how you parse the links. I personally prefer using `BeautifulSoup` over `xpath`, as using CSS selectors on classes or IDs is IMO more readable than your lengthy paths.

Note that in the end you will always be limited by your available internet connection. If you need to download 30 million 1 MB images with a 100Mbit/s internet connection, it will [take at least 27 days](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=30E6%20*%201MB%20%2F%20100%20Mbit%2Fs) and if you have a 1 Gbit/s connection it will still take almost three days no matter how you improve your code. If you download two images in parallel, each will just download at half the speed.

Comment: Crikey, thanks so much a lot that's a lot of help! I actually have decided to use BeautifulSoup now, I didn't originally as from my experience it uses a lot more memory (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284643/python-high-memory-usage-with-beautifulsoup, for example) but in the end, the ease of BeautifulSoup outweighed the benefits of saving a small amount of memory using the lxml lib.

Comment: Just one small thing you might have done by accident, you have an accent in there in `ǵet_title(tree)`.